# Rhino Mocks gives exception when calling Expect

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

When I run the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{     
    var navigationTree = MockRepository.GenerateMock<TreeOverlay>();

    navigationTree.Expect(i => i.AddExplicitNode(null, null)).IgnoreArguments().Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
}
```

I get the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what it says, `AddExplicitNode` should be virtual

Comment: So it can override it. Right. Thanks.